# Database mapping for Liferay User Management (6.2 version)?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I wanted to understand the database mapping in detail for Liferay User Management system. Do I get any reference where I can I Database mapping in any format like (ER diagrams / Block diagrams). Please give me some references for complete analysis of liferay database user management(6.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no offical ER diagram of data base schema. use workbench for reverse engineering the sql files